# What do GCS bucket permissions 'All Users' and 'All Authenticated Users' and the groups mean?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have created a bucket for my Google cloud project, that has default permissions for 'All Users', 'All Authenticated Users' and 3 pre-defined groups. What do all these mean?

I want to give read permissions to the objects inside the bucket to all (public) and write to bucket permissions to only my application and application editors. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3 pre-defined groups are for following:

1. **Project Owners**
2. **Project Editors**
3. **All Project Team Members**

The two additional groups are:

1. **All Users** - This grants public access
2. **All Authenticated Users** - This means all users logged in with Google account.

For more details, see:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#defaultbuckets

You need to pass the project-owner group and the key in the client API from your application, when you want full control from your project.

To give read access to public, you can select 'Read' against 'All Users' in the bucket. objects should take the bucket's default permissions, if not specified while creating the objects.

Comment: i have assigned "**Storage Object Viewer**" role to `allAuthenticatedUsers` for my object. But, when i use the object's "**Public URL**" to view the object from the same browser, I get a "Access denied" error - "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object." However, when i change that role to `allUsers` it works. I am certain that i am logged in to my google account from the same browser. Why does it not work when i set the "**Storage Object Viewer**" role to `allAuthenticatedUsers` but it works when i set the role to `allUsers`.

Comment: Public URLs are for anonymous, unauthenticated access (e.g. a standard web browser GET request)

Comment: @Rakib Were you able to resolve the `allAuthenticatedUsers` issue?

Comment: @datalifenyc nope. Still using `allUsers`.